# Show HUD in Osu! Standard Relax mod

Tags: osu

I've been playing Osu! Standard for a few months now and sometimes I like to play the relax mod. But I was wondering if there is a way to show the hud whilst using this mod. Or at least a way to show which circle's you did and didn't hit.

Answer (score 3):

With the relax mod, there's not a way to check what your acc, score or combo is until after you've finished the play. Even when watching the replay, you won't be able to view any of this.

Edit: This is now possible. I think it shows by default now but you can press Shift+Tab to show the HUD now.